# How to use Group by in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm using this sql query to get the product list from DB.

```
SELECT distinct P.product_id, B.brand_name, P.product_name,  P.product_description,   SC.sub_category_name, P.product_image_path
FROM table_products as P
INNER JOIN table_brands as B 
ON P.brand_id = B.brand_id

INNER JOIN table_product_categories as PC 
ON P.product_id = PC.product_id


INNER JOIN table_subcategories as SC
ON SC.sub_categories_id = PC.category_id

INNER JOIN table_subcategory_categories as SCC
ON SC.sub_categories_id = SCC.subcategory_id
ORDER BY P.product_id DESC";
```

It works fine for me. But when same product is in multiple subcategories. It gives me a new row. I just wanted to avoid this and wants  GROUP by with SC.sub_category_name. So when a product is in multiple categories, all the categories should list in same row.

Current

1. 853 Tops Premium Vermicelli /images/tops/853.png    Noodles
2. 853 Tops Premium Vermicelli /images/tops/853.png    Vermicelli

Expecting

1. 853 Tops Premium Vermicelli /images/tops/853.png    Noodles, Vermicelli

Comment: That sounds to need a transform, not a group by. Have you consider doing this logic in application, not database query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT()` for that purpose, grouping by `SC.sub_category_name` and remove the `distinct`. Something like

```
SELECT P.product_id, 
B.brand_name, 
P.product_name,  
P.product_description,   
GROUP_CONCAT(SC.sub_category_name) as sub_cat_list, 
P.product_image_path
FROM table_products P
INNER JOIN table_brands B 
ON P.brand_id = B.brand_id

INNER JOIN table_product_categories PC 
ON P.product_id = PC.product_id


INNER JOIN table_subcategories SC
ON SC.sub_categories_id = PC.category_id

INNER JOIN table_subcategory_categories SCC
ON SC.sub_categories_id = SCC.subcategory_id
GROUP BY P.product_id
ORDER BY P.product_id DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Suggested change is concating all the products of a subcategory. I just want to concat the subcategories (if product is in 2 or more subcategories) not the products.

Comment: Devesh, Can you post some sample data along with the desired output. That will clear about what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: Rahul, I added the sample data in the post.

Comment: Thanks Rahul. I'm able to achieve what i wanted to by referring your response.

Comment: That's great but From your edited data; I think you wanted to group by `p.product_id` and concatenating `SC.sub_category_name` instead.

Comment: Yes right. group by p.product_id and GROUP_CONCAT(SC.sub_category_name)